# How do I create a embeddable widget in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, widget

I would like to create a embeddable widget that can be included in other website using an iframe(or any other possible methods).The widget should get the data from the user and send it to the rails application. Its like embedding a complete web app in an another website or web application. The widget should work just by providing a single line of JavaScript include tag something similar to [Zopim Live Chat](https://www.zopim.com/)  .

Comment: @SachinSingh I completely used javascript for this.

Comment: @PremAnand could you post an answer to this?

Comment: Sorry i can't do it now. Will do it when i'm free

Answer (score -4):

As I think, Rails is wrong tool for such kind of work.
But you may to refactor your task and do it another way.
So, you want to include your app to other web-sites. For this you may add a widget into that web-site (with using js or similar). The widget will send data to your rails-app and you will need to handle this kind of request.

For example, you want to find a subscribers for your mailing list. You need to create a form (that can be handled with AJAX [but be shure about cross-origir requests] or simple POST request) to send you a nessesery information about subscriber. Next, you will need to create an action to add a subscriber and create a route for this. After these preparations you will be able to add this form (you may create it with js) as a widget to any site you want and this form (in mailing list case) will send you a proper informations.

Hope this helps.